# Leagues top bar overlaps row after following the link

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues, anchor

When you go from a user page (for example `https://stackoverflow.com/users/14928633/kirogasa`) by clicking link:

> [image]

to the rating page (`https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow/2022-10-01/14928633#14928633`), the top bar overlaps the row on which the user is located:

> [image]

and you have to scroll to the top of the page to see the values:

> [image]

Comment: As far as I can tell it's not the top bar, something with the anchor is off, couldn't figure what exactly.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard nope, it's precisely the topbar that causes this because it has a fixed `position`. The anchor is located correctly - if you disable the stickiness of the sidebar (remove the `ps-fixed` class), you'll see that the row has been scrolled into view correctly.

Comment: As for how to fix it, it's a bit complicated because the top bar is removed from the normal document flow. An obvous solution is to push the page content downward to top bar's height. That said, there are some drawbacks to it (for example, SE has to assume the top bar has fixed height).